# converting (and saving) geometry type in geopandas

Tags: python, gis, shapefile, geopandas, shapely

I have a GeoDataFrame containing linear-rings that I want to (conditionally) convert to polygons. Sounds easy:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

def update_geom(row):
    if (row.aoi_type=='blocks') or (row.aoi_type=='locale'):
        return Polygon(row.geometry)
    else:
        return row.geometry

gdf['geometry']=gdf.apply(update_geom,axis=1)
```

This seemingly works great - if I inspect the GeoDataFrame I can see `LINESTRING(...)` => `POLYGON(...)`, and `gdf.sample().iloc[0].geometry` correctly plots the shape as a polygon in a notebook.

But here is where it gets weird. When I do this ...

```py
gdf.to_file('filename',index=False)
updated_gdf=gpd.read_file('filename')
```

`updated_gdf` is back to having `LINESTRING()`'s again.

Thoughts? Fixes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saving to shapefile (which seems from your code), you face the limitation of the file format. SHP supports only one geometry type. So while GeoDataFrame is fine with mixed LineStrings and Polygons in one geometry columns, shapefile is not and allows you to keep only one.

You can either try another format (like GeoJSON) or split GeoDataFrame into two based on geometry type before saving to (two) shapefiles.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea shp files were limited to a single type :)